# Why can't I use Ñ in my XML output, when declared as UTF-8?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have the 'N Tilde' character Ñ in my Z/OS DB2 database. I am generating an xml file from the data. In the XML I have `encoding=UTF-8`, however Internet Explorer gives me the error `Illegal character in text field`. If I change the encoding to ISO-8859-1 it works fine.

I thought ISO-8859-1 was a subset of UTF-8, so why is it not working with UTF-8?

Is UTF-8 the best for an XML document?

Comment: *How* are you generating the xml file from the data?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is not a subset of UTF-8

Comment: I am adding the XML tags manually.

Comment: How do I convert the data to UTF-8?

Comment: You can try using a conversion program such as `iconv` to convert between encodings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ISO-8859-1 is **not** a subset of UTF-8. It can represent a subset of the characters representable in UTF-8, but it doesn't do so in the same way.

Both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 are supersets of ASCII (i.e. they can represent all characters that ASCII can represent and they represent them in the same way).

So you can't just label ISO-8859-1 data as UTF-8 and hope that it works, you need to actually store (or convert) your data as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

## UTF-8 ≠ Unicode

Note carefully:

- ASCII is a subset of ISO 8859-1.
- ASCII is a subset of Unicode.
- ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.
- ISO 8859-1 *is* a subset of Unicode.
- ISO 8859-1 *is not* a subset of UTF-8.
- **Unicode is not the same thing as UTF-8.**

I strongly advise familiarizing oneself with the subtleties in [modern terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Terminology).

If that’s too confusing, you might look at [Radix-50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50), which has a repertoire many order of magnitude smaller than Unicode’s, but which nevertheless manifests several of the same subtleties that now escape people with respect to Unicode, character repertoires, coded character sets, character encoding forms, and  character encoding schemes.

### Java `chars` Incapable of Holding Characters

Since you’re coming at this from Java, it really isn’t your fault that these aren’t clearly separate concepts in your mind.  That’s because Java gravely confuses these issue by not separating out the abstact code points (the logical characters) of a **coded character set** from the down-and-dirty mechanics of one particular **character encoding form**.

Java’s miserable conflation of `chars` with logical characters is error-prone in the extremely; perhaps it would be more accurate to say that Java programmers’ conflation of the same is miserable.  In any event, there now seems to be no hope of remedy, *ever*.

Blame it all on the hysterical porpoises if you must, but the most charitable thing you can say about it is that it is highly unfortunate.  Because of all this, well-meaning and perfectly competent  programmers like yourself will forever be easily confused, and so will  continually write Java code that is simple, clear, and wrong.

Education  about all this is the only possible palliative, but it is no true cure.

Comment: "ASCII is a subset of Unicode" is not exactly true, since "Unicode" is not an encoding.

Comment: To be fair: when Java was initially created, it **could** actually hold all possible, assigned Unicode codepoints in its `char` datatype. (Unicode 1.1 was current at the time and had no codepoints assigned outside of the BMP).

Comment: @Joachim: Unicode is a mapping number -> character, as is ASCII. ASCII maps some of these numbers (those below 128) to the same characters as Unicode. *Submapping* would be more precise than subset, though.

Comment: @Paŭlo: the difference is that Unicode doesn't (directly) specify any mapping to physical bytes, while ASCII does. For Unicode that step is handled by encodings such as UCS-4, UTF-16, UTF-8 and so on. Put differently: what would be the actual bytes of representing "Hello" in Unicode?

Comment: @Joachim: You are right, Unicode does not specify bytes, only numbers. But ASCII in fact is both: specifying numbers **and** bytes. And one could say Unicode is a superset (supermap?) of the number-part of ASCII, while UTF-8 (and Latin-1 and some more) are supersets (supermappings) of the byte-encoding part of ASCII.

Comment: And Unicode is a superset of the number-part of Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 1):

ISO-8859-1 is not at all a subset of UTF-8. ASCII is a subset of both ISO-8859-1 *and* UTF-8. They specifically differ for characters in the Unicode code point range of U+0080 - U+00FF.

In ISO-8859-1, the character 'Ñ' (U+00D1 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE) is represented as the single byte `D1`. In UTF-8, the same character is represented by the two byte sequence `C3 91`.

Comment: So how do I convert to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

For generating XML in Java, best thing to do would to use an XML library - this also ensures that everything is well-formed.

If you *must* create it by hand, best use `new OutputStreamWriter(stream, encoding)`, where encoding is the same encoding as you are writing in your XML preamble.

Also make sure that the Strings you get from your database are encoded the right way.